# update a mongodb collection in php

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to update a part of mongodb collection in php. So I passed two parameters $id and $val using html form and I would like to update the value of a document with id=$id to val=$val. this is what I did so far in my php code, but I couldn't still get the document updated. your help is needed

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db=$connection->mydb;
$user_collection=$db->mycollection;
$user_collection->update({"_id": ObjectId($id)},{$set: "value":$val}});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`{"_id": ObjectId($id)},{$set: "value":$val}}` is by no means valid PHP code, please see how arrays shall be written

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax as far as I know is -

```
$user_collection->updateOne(['_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id)], ['$set' => ['value' => $val]]);
```